# Failed to compare two elements in the array. At least one object must implement IComparable

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Below is code in which I am trying to get all Client and Roles for a user just top latest version record. So output in below is..this works fine in Standalone mode as below but when I add this code in my project which is on .net core 2.1.x it gives error "Failed to compare two elements in the array.\r\n At least one object must implement IComparable ", **how to fix it, any suggestion ?**

```
Solution #1
4 VIEW 1
3 ADMIN 2
```

Code

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
public class Simple {
  public static void Main() {
            var userRoles = (new[] 
            { 
            new { clientid=1 , rowVersion = 1 , role="READ" },
            new { clientid=1 , rowVersion = 2 , role="EDIT" },
            new { clientid=2 , rowVersion = 3 , role="ADMIN" },
            new { clientid=1 , rowVersion = 4 , role="VIEW" }
        });


      var results = userRoles.GroupBy(x => x.clientid)
                  .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.rowVersion).First());


      Console.WriteLine("Solution #1");

      foreach (var k in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", k.rowVersion, k.role, k.clientid);
        }

  }
  }
```

**UPDATE**
Got the solution adding below as Answer.

RootCause is "Anonymous types are not order comparable."

Comment: Can you post the code block that you used on your project? Especially the class of userRoles variable. Is it anonymous in your code also?

Comment: Also, it would help if you post all of the exception message including the whole stack trace

Comment: The code is working on my computer in a Console Application.

Comment: I believe issue is you can't use OrderBy in anonymous way.

Comment: added solution in this thread below

Comment: Why giving negative rank ? what is the reason ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the working solution for above issue. Issue is "Anonymous types are not order comparable."

```
 var results = userRoles
                       .OrderByDescending(y => y.rowVersion)
                       .GroupBy(x => x.clientid)
                       .SelectMany(x => x.Take(1));
```

This works all good.